# Python - Is it possible to create games on python in different OS?

Tags: python, android, ios, windows

I like Python language because it is minimalistic language. Python is interpreted and dynamic as JavaScript, but it is pretty short on eyes than JavaScript or JS. I mean visual syntax of Python is short and minimalistic. I would like to write my programs in Python on MacOS under different systems such Windows, Linux of course Android and IOS

My question is - is it possible to create cross platform e.g. games in python? Windows, Linux of course Android and IOS operation systems? 2D games? 3D games? Not simple tick take toe?

Answer (score 1):

yes of course you can create not only games but other softwares like calculator etc
there are some libraries by which you can start making your own game using python
libraries:pygame turtle etc (google it)